# 1 jekyll vulnerability found in Gemfile.lock on Sep 16, 2019

Tags: jekyll

I get this message in my github pages branch: 
"1 jekyll vulnerability found in Gemfile.lock on Sep 16, 2019'. Upgrade jekyll to version 3.6.3 or later. For example:
gem "jekyll", ">= 3.6.3"
There were too issues before, one with nokogiri which I addressed by updating to the latest version of the gem, then commit and push.
I have already updated Jekyll to version 4.0 and then committed and pushed the whole site but the error has not gone away.
Any suggestions?
Should I push any file in particular?
Thanks

Comment: Without a repository url it will be difficult to investigate.

Comment: Here it is: https://github.com/marcelolalvarez/my-professional-website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your **Gemfile** is not properly updated, it still mentions `gem "jekyll", "~> 3.2.1"` which is also referenced in your **Gemfile.lock**.

Nevertheless, if you publish on github pages, the only gem you need to reference is `github-pages`.

Your Gemfile content :

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'github-pages'
```

You can then do a `bundle update` and push your code to github, every security warning will be gone.

Comment: Ok thanks. When you say "push your code" you are referring to push my whole site to github or a file in particular? If so, which one?

Comment: I did a bundle update, and then pushed the code but still the same issue

Comment: https://github.com/marcelolalvarez/my-professional-website/blob/master/Gemfile is still the same since 6 months. Are you sure that your pushing in the right repository ?

Comment: That is exactly what my gemfile says in my local. I am not sure why it is not getting updated after doing the bundle update? Is there a way to update this file manually?

Comment: Re-read my answer and change your Gemfile content accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Your Gemfile is locked to `jekyll-3.2.x`.

No matter how many times you run `bundle update`, your lockfile is going not going to use Jekyll 3.3 and above.
To allow upgrading to `v3.3.0` and above but not `v4.0.0`, the gem listing need to be:

```
gem "jekyll", "~> 3.2"
```

---

Understand the following:

- `gem "jekyll", "~> 3.2.1"` is the same as `gem "jekyll", ">= 3.2.1", "< 3.3.0"`
- `gem "jekyll", "~> 3.2"` is the same as `gem "jekyll", ">= 3.2.0", "< 4.0.0"`

---

---

The above said, the correct move here is what David Jacquel said in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60656909/7681659). Let me summarize what he meant:

- *Update your Gemfile to list just the `github-pages` gem* — the gem includes the needed plugins as well.
- Commit updated `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock`.
- Push branch to remote repository.